# Why do we say "было" instead of "были"?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

Why do we say **"у него было много энергии и большой талант"** and we don’t use **"были"**?

Comment: Could you please give a more suitable title to your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Были* followed by *много* sounds unnatural, maybe because *много* is undefined and uncountable.

It's okay however to say *"у него были энергия и талант"* or *"у него были талант и много энергии"*.

Comment: Is there a resource where one could find a thorough explanation on which form of был/были/было one has to use, in sentences like "There is / isn't something" or "Someone has /has not something" ?

Comment: @MattiP. There is no need in any axtra resource. The verb should correspond to the gender and number of the noun as in any other sentence - у него был стол (singular, male), у него была собака (singular, female), у него было зеркало (singular, neuter), у него были гости (plural).

Answer (score 0):

Because "было" is in front of "много энергии и большой талант" it is preferable to use singular "было" rather than multiple.

> Сложность вызывает согласование сказуемого с несколькими  подлежащими.
>
> При прямом порядке слов сказуемое ставится в форме множественного
>   числа, при обратном сказуемое согласуется с ближайшим из подлежащих.
>
> Сравните: Ее судьба, ее конец// Непроницаемою тьмою// От нас закрыты.
>   и Погиб и кормщик и пловец (А.С. Пушкин).

http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=5.2